# Chromium on ubuntu GLX issues

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, chromium, opengl

I am trying to run `chromium-browser` on Ubuntu Server but it starts with a lot of errors that you can see below.

I have tried to installed the Nvidia drivers, update/install everything related to GLX/openGL, start chromium with `--disable-gpu params` but nothing seems to work.

Chromium DOES start but unfortunately it blocks my program execution which is not the case when running the same program on my Mac.

I am running `vnc4server` on Ubuntu, and using Vnc Viewer on my MAC.

```
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".
[2386:2471:0421/104017.549638:ERROR:bus.cc(394)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[2386:2406:0421/104017.549743:ERROR:in_progress_cache_impl.cc(93)] Could not read download entries from file because there was a read failure.
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".
[2475:2475:0421/104017.608784:ERROR:gl_surface_glx.cc(428)] GLX 1.3 or later is required.
[2475:2475:0421/104017.608812:ERROR:gl_initializer_x11.cc(157)] GLSurfaceGLX::InitializeOneOff failed.
[2475:2475:0421/104017.618425:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(197)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization

(chromium-browser:2386): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Unable to get session bus: Unknown or unsupported transport 'disabled' for address 'disabled:'
[2386:2417:0421/104017.654409:ERROR:service_manager_context.cc(252)] Attempting to run unsupported native service: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/content_gpu.service
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".
[2520:2520:0421/104017.689388:ERROR:gl_surface_glx.cc(428)] GLX 1.3 or later is required.
[2520:2520:0421/104017.689419:ERROR:gl_initializer_x11.cc(157)] GLSurfaceGLX::InitializeOneOff failed.
[2520:2520:0421/104017.692224:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(197)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[2386:2417:0421/104017.694527:ERROR:service_manager_context.cc(252)] Attempting to run unsupported native service: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/content_gpu.service
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".
[2624:2624:0421/104017.740368:ERROR:gl_implementation.cc(292)] Failed to load /usr/lib/chromium-browser/swiftshader/libGLESv2.so: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/swiftshader/libGLESv2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[2624:2624:0421/104017.742284:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(197)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[2386:2417:0421/104017.743324:ERROR:service_manager_context.cc(252)] Attempting to run unsupported native service: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/content_gpu.service
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".
[2634:2634:0421/104017.780159:ERROR:gl_implementation.cc(292)] Failed to load /usr/lib/chromium-browser/swiftshader/libGLESv2.so: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/swiftshader/libGLESv2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[2634:2634:0421/104017.782369:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(197)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[2386:2417:0421/104017.783364:ERROR:service_manager_context.cc(252)] Attempting to run unsupported native service: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/content_gpu.service
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".
[2642:2642:0421/104017.819844:ERROR:gl_implementation.cc(292)] Failed to load /usr/lib/chromium-browser/swiftshader/libGLESv2.so: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/swiftshader/libGLESv2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[2642:2642:0421/104017.821634:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(197)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[2386:2417:0421/104017.822766:ERROR:service_manager_context.cc(252)] Attempting to run unsupported native service: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/content_gpu.service
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".
[2650:2650:0421/104017.858141:ERROR:gl_implementation.cc(292)] Failed to load /usr/lib/chromium-browser/swiftshader/libGLESv2.so: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/swiftshader/libGLESv2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[2650:2650:0421/104017.859995:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(197)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[2386:2417:0421/104017.861061:ERROR:service_manager_context.cc(252)] Attempting to run unsupported native service: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/content_gpu.service
[2386:2417:0421/104017.862808:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(120)] Failed to launch GPU process.
[2386:2386:0421/104017.862892:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1019)] Lost UI shared context.
[2386:2417:0421/104017.993026:ERROR:upload_data_presenter.cc(73)] Not implemented reached in virtual void extensions::RawDataPresenter::FeedNext(const net::UploadElementReader &)
[2386:2417:0421/104018.023866:ERROR:upload_data_presenter.cc(73)] Not implemented reached in virtual void extensions::RawDataPresenter::FeedNext(const net::UploadElementReader &)
[2386:2417:0421/104018.066602:ERROR:upload_data_presenter.cc(73)] Not implemented reached in virtual void extensions::RawDataPresenter::FeedNext(const net::UploadElementReader &)
```